# Return string method that contains a lambda expression

Tags: c#, string, lambda, return

I am trying to return a string from a lambda expression. This expression can print out the received strings with writeline but I can't figure out how to return the string from the function so I could use it all over my project.

Thanks

```
public static async Task<string> messaging_server() 
{
    using (var messagebus1 = new TinyMessageBus("ExampleChannel"))
    {
        messagebus1.MessageReceived +=
        (sender, e) => Debug.writeLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));

        while (true)
        {
             #infinite loop        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in a local variable and use a multi-line lambda expression, like this:

```
public static async Task<string> messaging_server() 
{
    string ret;

    using (var messagebus1 = new TinyMessageBus("ExampleChannel"))  
    {

        messagebus1.MessageReceived += (sender, e) => 
        {
            ret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
            Debug.writeLine(ret);
        };

        while (true)
        {
            //#infinite loop        
        }

    }  

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the method is poorly-named: `messaging_server`.  This doesn't conform to the accepted naming convention for methods, which is Pascal case, or upper camel case.

Comment: And no underscores. And should not be a noun.

Comment: @eurotrash -- Pascal case implies no underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly maybe you can try like this:

```
    public static async Task<string> messaging_server() {
    using (var messagebus1 = new TinyMessageBus("ExampleChannel"))

    {

        messagebus1.MessageReceived +=
        (sender, e) => 
        { 
            var encodedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(encodedMessage);
            return encodedMessage;
        } 


        while (true)
        {
            #infinite loop        
        }
    }

}
```

Please note how I wrapped `Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));`. It will print and it will return encoded `e.Message`.

Comment: Multiple occurrences of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message)` is not DRY.

Comment: @rory.ap You are right. I applied your suggestion. It was just

Comment: Why it will never run? In my local it runs properly.